# Cmake for a library with a single .h file

Tags: c++, cmake

Surely this is a very basic question on cmake,...

I wonder if it is possible or if it makes sense to create a static library like : libhelloword.a
from a single .h file of cpp code.

I wrote the CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

SET(LIB_HELLOWORLD    "helloworld")

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
)

ADD_LIBRARY(${LIB_HELLOWORLD} STATIC
  helloworld.h
)
```

unfortunately this does not work.

I get

```
-- Configuring done
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:12 (ADD_LIBRARY):
  Cannot find source file:

    helloworld.h

  Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm .hpp
  .hxx .in .txx


-- Build files have been written to: /path/to/files
```

and I cannot run make since no makefile was created

Any help would be highly appreciated since I am lost in this cmake world :p

BTW: The .h file is an external library which (surely) I cannot modify.

Comment: What does your file structure look like?

Comment: What's the point of creating header-only static library? `The .h file is an external library` do you mean you have external already-build library and `helloworld.h` is interface header?

Answer (score 0):

How are you going to use this library? Anyway you'll need to include it's header to you execution module. So, all the code from this header will be compiled there.

But if you really want, you can create helloworld.cpp include helloworld.h in it and modify CMakeList.txt in this way:

```
ADD_LIBRARY(${LIB_HELLOWORLD} STATIC helloworld.cpp)
```